LINUX: ping между портами одного устройства
Необходимо проверить корректную работу сетевых портов устройства, для чего применяется iperf3. Порты на устройстве попарно соединяются друг с другом, им присваиваются временные адреса, после чего запускается n-ое количество окон iperf3, гоняющие трафик между портами. На втором цикле порты-клиенты меняются местами с портами-серверами.
Для Windows написание нужного скрипта не стало проблемой, но в Linux (Astra Linux 1.7.5) наткнулся на то, что невозможно идентифицировать связанные порты: ping проходит от любого порта к любому. Как я понял, сигнал идёт через ядро, а не "по проводу". Есть ли возможность это обойти?
Пока что я нашёл выход через создание отдельного Network ns, куда переносится интерфейс, ему присваивается IP, и ping`ом находится пара из оставшихся интерфейсов, после чего в этот ns переносится следующий интерфейс. Проблема в том, что для инициализации и подъема интерфейса системе необходимо минимум 4 секунды (иначе ping просто упрётся в состояние DOWN), и поднять их все за один такт не выйдет никак. На машине может быть до 48 портов, и тогда только на одно соединение таким способом будет тратиться непозволительно много времени.
Вопрос: есть ли более изящный способ обнаружения связанных друг с другом интерфейсов?

да, arping -I порт IP-адрес - отправит запрос с нужного порта, а не через ядро. так же рекомендую почитать про параметры net.ipv4.conf.all.arp_ignore = 1
net.ipv4.conf.all.arp_announce = 2

@balbes Благодарю за ответ. Утилиту попробовал, пока получаю лишь Timeout (как на пробной сети, так и на собственной, рабочей).

на другой стороне кабеля должен быть порт с присвоенным IP адресом, который и надо пинговать. Посмотрите у утилиты ключь -s

@balbes, Чтобы не быть голословным, присылаю использованные команды и вывод от них:
`$ sudo ip addr

6: eth4: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc mq state UP group default qlen 1000
inet 192.168.152.3/24 brd 192.168.152.255 scope global dynamic eth4
***
7: eth5: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc mq state UP group default qlen 1000
inet 192.168.152.1/24 brd 192.168.152.255 scope global dynamic eth5

$ sudo arping -S 192.168.152.1 192.168.152.3
ARPING 192.168.152.3
Timeout`

Соответственно, разные комбинации IP и ключей (-S -s -T -p -I) выдают один и тот же ответ - Timeout. С сетями я раньше дел почти не имел, но могу только предположить, что арпинг как-то использует для своей работы арп-таблицы, которые, судя по arp -a, на машине пусты.

arping -I ethX - этот ключ обязателен в Вашем случае. Надо указывать исходящий интерфейс. Если и после этого таймаут, значит порты физически не соеденены между собой по L2

Данную комбинацию также пробовал:
$sudo arping -I eth5 -S 192.168.152.1 192.168.152.3 (и другие сочетания IP). Результат тот же. Попробовал также работать не с петлями на конечном устройстве, а подключить его к роутеру, и использовать выданные dhcp-сервером адреса: результат - таймаут.

Значит у Вас тестируемые порты по L2 не соеденены между собой.
